# Provide ID to dynamically generated cloned element

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am dragging and dropping some element (with the help of Kendo UI) and generating the new element that are the clone element of draggable elements, my problem is that I want to provide new id to them? How can I do that?

Comment: Did you try using `kendo.guid()`? You can use it for generating a new one. So clone the node and then generate a new `guid` and assigning it to the cloned element

Comment: @OnaBai thanks for your response but i could not found any reference regarding kendo.guid(), so can you provide me any link or example so that i can get the proper syntax for this.

Comment: right now i am doing it like
 var newEl = $(e.draggable.currentTarget).clone();
        newEl.id = kendo.guid();
but this generating a random id that i cant access to apply style in  the same element..correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Don't think it is documented. It is internally use by KendoUI for generating unique ids. See it running here http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/r6HUw/

Comment: Can you post the full code or show it JSFiddle or JSBin?

Comment: here is my complete example http://jsfiddle.net/akki166786/rTxaE/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being `droptargetOnDrop` your `drop` event handler, you should do:

```
function droptargetOnDrop(e) {
    var newEl = $(e.draggable.currentTarget).clone();
    newEl.attr("id",kendo.guid()); 
    e.dropTarget.append(newEl);
}
```

See your fiddle modified running here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/rTxaE/2/